# Replace text with empty string by class in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to create a js function which removes text onclick from a certain class of fields in HTML.

When checking Yes in the trigger (onclick), the function is not clearing the data in my target.

This works if I substitute id for class where appropriate, but I need the function to affect 10+ html fields. Can this be accomplished by class?

Note: There is a little extra in the HTML below because there is another js function run onclick in my trigger. I've removed the divs, so it's less cluttered.

JavaScript

```
function eraseText() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("eraseonupdate").value = "";
}
```

HTML

Trigger:

```
<input type="radio" name="exceptionupdate" class="_exceptionupdate" value="Yes" onclick="ExceptionUpdate();eraseText()" />Yes <input type="radio" name="exceptionupdate" class="_exceptionupdate" value="No" onclick="ExceptionUpdate()" />No
```

Target:

```
<input type="text" name="Approver" size="20" class="eraseonupdate">
```

Comment: Obtain all elements by using the query selector and for each of them clear the text.

Comment: getElementsByClassName does not return an Element but instead returns a list of Elements. So, you should traverse over them and change their values one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the result of `.getElementsByClassName()`, to make that easier you can convert it to an array, like so:

```js
function eraseText() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('eraseonupdate');
  
  Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach(function(el) {
    el.value = '';
  });
  
  // if you do not need old browsers to work you could do
  /*
  [...elements].forEach(el => {
    el.value = '';
  });
  */
}

function ExceptionUpdate() {
  return;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Approver" size="20" class="eraseonupdate">

<label><input type="radio" name="exceptionupdate" class="_exceptionupdate" value="Yes" onclick="ExceptionUpdate();eraseText()" />Yes</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="exceptionupdate" class="_exceptionupdate" value="No" onclick="ExceptionUpdate()" />No</label>
```

Comment: Crazy that this is the accepted answer. It's very good but maybe not the most beginner friendly. However the OP did not specify it.

Comment: you mean a for-loop would be more beginner friendly? The 'nicest' looking one would probably be `[...elements].forEach(...)`, but that might not work in crappy browsers, so I stayed on the "safe" side with `Array.prototype...`, but yeah, you might be right...I did clean it up a bit to make it more readable though...

Comment: Yeah I agree with the forEach() and yes a for-loop is more beginner friendly to me. Both @Vanita and yours combined would be a godlike answer :)

Answer (score 4):

That's because the two methods return different values.

`getElementById` will return one HTML object (as an `id` should be unique).
`getElementsByClassName` will return a HTMLCollection (as classes do not need to be unique). To alter the value of each of the items in this collection, you need to loop over them.

For example

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("eraseonupdate");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = ""
}
```

Comment: Clear and good answer! One remark though, they are indeed different but in this case it's probably better to choose an id over a class. So maybe edit your answer how to change html class to id.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` does technically NOT return an array but a `HTMLCollection` which is array-like, but doesn't have the common array-methods, if you want a real array, you need to convert it to one, for example like this `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('classname'))`

Comment: Good point @exside, have updated to reference HTML Collection instead.

Comment: Or you could use `for(element of elements)`.

Answer (score 0):

Call to `getElementsByClassName("class")` returns a collection of elements. Iterate over them and clear value in a loop. Use `value` or other attribute or `innerHTML` depending on your need:

```
function clearText() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
    [...elements].forEach(element => {
        element.value = "";
        // element.innerHTML="";
    });
}
```

Instead of `[...elements].forEach()` you may use `Array.from(elements).forEach()`.